# How to get latest record in union with angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, underscore.js

I have a 2 json array list in AngularJS, now i am use `union` to get records without duplication like this.

```
var s = _.union(array1,array2)
```

Now, `array1` have some records which are already in `array2`, but result have always old entry from `array1`, but i want latest record from `array2`.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Can you provide example values for array1 and array2?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the sort() function as well.  Like this:

```
var array1 = [1, 2, 3];
var array2 = [3, 4, 5];
var combined = _.union(array1, array2).sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
});
```